# Rails 4 and Devise - User registration via JSON API

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm attempting to register a devise user via JSON but keep getting an `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationsController  < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  def create

    user = User.new(params[:user])

    if user.save
      render :json => user.as_json(:auth_token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email), :status=>201
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json => user.errors, :status=>422
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end

end
```

Here's my JSON request:

```
 Processing by Api::V1::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
 Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"jayson@jayson.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"jayson@jayson.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
```

I realize this has something to do with Strong Parameters but haven't been able to crack it yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would change:

```
user = User.new(params[:user])
```

with:

```
user = User.new(user_params)
```

From docs:

```
# This will raise an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception because it's using mass assignment
# without an explicit permit step.
def create
  Person.create(params[:person])
end
```